# C# - How to manage ProgressEvent while Reading(iterating through) a MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, progress-bar, memorystream

I am writing a ClassLibrary which will Read a `MemoryStream` and again on the next Method it will Write to Another `MemoryStream`..

What I am trying to do is to provide `"something"` which will Handle Progress Events while performing both the Reading and Writing loops...

the Reading and Writing are not handled by the Form..
So, there is no way of updating the ProgressBar during reading

I am not sure where to start..

So I am asking for some suggestions and explanation!

Comment: Have you looked at the [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class yet?

Comment: You would put your logic in a BackgroundWorker. Then you would create an instance of your `BackgroundWorker` and subscribe to its `OnProgressChanged` event to display progress in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class yet? You could wrap your read/write functionality in a `BackgroundWorker` and devise a way to raise a `ProgressChanged` event (every so many bytes read/written, etc.). Your form (UI) can subscribe to the `OnProgressChanged` event that would update the progress of a progress bar or something.

**EDIT:** This is a very generalized description of the actual work you would need to complete. But all of the tiny things needed to set up an asynchronous background worker are pretty well explained in the above link. The hardest part for you will be incorporating the reading/writing of `MemoryStream`s, and figuring out the calculation of progress.

Comment: The example I linked to on MSDN has some pretty good examples.

Comment: Oh sorry I did not see the link! now i am going to the link!!Sorry!

Comment: I am very sure how to do the calculation of progress and i did that before when I first code the app and the code was on the Application itself..[not a separate class lib]..
So, I have to declare my class as a `BackgroundWorker` and handle those `DoWork()` and `ProgressChanged` events??

Comment: Yes, in a nutshell. It's up to you if you want to take care of the cancellation event. The example of calculating the Fibonacci sequence is pretty detailed, I would try to reverse engineer its parts.